# Relationship on same table with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

How can I specify a realtionship on the same table using Entity Framework?

My table 'Items' has the following fields: 
- Id (uniqueidentifier)
- ThreadId (uniqueidentifier)
- Created (datetime)
- Text (nvarchar(max))

My model 'Item': 
 - Id (Guid)
 - ThreadId (Guid)
 - Created (DateTime)
 - Text (string)
 - ChildItems (Icollection)

How can I create the relationship so that ChildItems holds the items with Id = ThreadId?

Comment: Do you mean using Code First approach or other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following shall do it:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                    .HasOptional(c => c.ChildItems)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ThreadId);
```

Answer (score 2):

The Item entity

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ThreadId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> ChildItems { get; set; }

    /* Other properties */
}
```

And the fluent configuration

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .HasMany(i => i.ChildItems)
                .WithOptional()
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.ThreadId);
```